# ajaxtoolkit smart tag not showing up

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while, but no solution till now.

I try to reinstall it but still , the smart tag are not showing up and when I right click it, it is grayed out.

Anyone, with a solution to solve this issue. I am using asp.net 3.5, visual studio 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a glitch in VS2008 or not, but I found a workaround.
Switch to Source view, and drag a control from you Ajax Control Toolkit onto the edit screen.
Then set the TargetControlId attribute to the name of the control you want to extend. Strangely enough, after doing this, the smart tag appears, although it only offers you the option of removing the extender.

Important: You need to remove the ScriptControlManager (if you have added one) from the page and replace it with the ToolkitScriptManagerControl.

I hope this hel

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
The previous answer I gave will circumvent the problem, but to get the smart tags you have to register the AjaxControlToolkit assembly on any web page where you want to use them like so:
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
This statement should go below the page declaration statement (top of web page).
That will give you the smart tags.
Note: Whatever you set as the "TagPrefix" needs to be used as the prefix to any toolkit control:

Best Wishes